# LINQ Left Join Error

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, left-join

I have 2 Generic Lists called **Students** and **Entries**  They are in 1 to 0..1 relationship.  Students 1:0..1 Entries

I want to get the list of Student Name, ID and English, Maths detail from Entries if exists.

My LINQ query is as below and I got the null reference error at **se.English**.  Could you pls help?  Thanks.

```
var query = from s in students
            join t in entries
            on s.StudentDetailID equals t.StudentDetailID into StudentEntries
            from se in StudentEntries.DefaultIfEmpty()                                    
            select new { s.StudentDetailID, s.LastName, s.FirstName,
            se.English};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`se` could be null, because you assigned it `StudentEntries.DefaultIfEmpty()`. And Default of a class is null. So you can't call `se.English` without testing it for null before:

```
var query = from s in students
        join t in entries
        on s.StudentDetailID equals t.StudentDetailID into StudentEntries
        from se in StudentEntries.DefaultIfEmpty()                                    
        select new { s.StudentDetailID, s.LastName, s.FirstName,
        se == null ? null : se.English};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have a 1-0..1 relationship so it is possible that se.english will be null(because you used an left outer join), you should handle it in your query, I assumed it it would be String and put "" if it is null, You can handle it as you wish.

```
var query = from s in students
            join t in entries
            on s.StudentDetailID equals t.StudentDetailID into StudentEntries
            from se in StudentEntries.DefaultIfEmpty()                                    
            select new { s.StudentDetailID, s.LastName, s.FirstName,
            English = se.English?? ""};
```